# How to parse xml file in sencha and get the tag value

Tags: sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

can anybody tell How to parse xml file in sencha and get the tag value

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the XML you are trying to phrase?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [XML Reader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml) in your proxy. You will find example in linked docs